# Why does the plan cache contain estimated and not actual execution plans?

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan, plan-cache

I can think of many reasons behind this decision of storing estimated plans in the plan cache and not the actual plan. But I can't find the "correct" answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Think about what "actual" means. It's what *actually* happens for the execution of that plan.

Another common name for the actual execution plan is the **"post execution plan"**.  As a real world example to correlate this scenario, say you plan to go on a cross country trip, so you plot out the roads you're going to take and how long you think it'll take. But because of road work and detours, it doesn't happen *quite* like you planned. That's the actual execution plan:  The actual route that you took to get to where you're going.  The estimated plan would have been what you *thought* you'd be doing, and what route you *thought* you should take.

*You can't store post execution plans because they are just that....post execution*. They contain metrics of what *really* happened, not what SQL Server thinks should happen (estimated execution plan).

The plan cache is really just a repository of **"maps" that it can reuse without having to spend the expensive time to draw up a new one**. Actual execution plans are *after the fact*, and the plan cache is to handle *before the fact*.